# How to send ktor-client 'POST' without "; charset=UTF-8"

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor-client

I want to use ktor in my android aplication to send 'POST' to the device.

```
override suspend fun main() {
    val response: HttpResponse = client.post("https://pie.dev/post") {
        headers {
            append(HttpHeaders.ContentType, ContentType.Application.FormUrlEncoded.toString())
        }
        setBody(FormDataContent(Parameters.build {append(KEY, "KeyValue")}))
    }
    println(response.bodyAsText())
}
```

My problem is that device accepts headers like this: `"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`, and ktos adds `"; charset=UTF-8"`. How to enforce content-type to be without `"; charset=UTF-8"`?

I've tried add `.withoutParameters()` - not working